# iokit.IOServiceGetMatchingServices broken under Python3?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyserial

I just got a mac mini running Yosemite (I normally use linux). I was trying to get serial.tools.list_ports.comports() to work under Python3.

I've narrowed down the problem to the following snippet of code (extracted from pyserial):

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import util

iokit = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(ctypes.util.find_library('IOKit'))

kIOMasterPortDefault = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(iokit, "kIOMasterPortDefault")

iokit.IOServiceMatching.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

iokit.IOServiceGetMatchingServices.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
iokit.IOServiceGetMatchingServices.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

serial_port_iterator = ctypes.c_void_p()

print('kIOMasterPortDefault =', kIOMasterPortDefault)

response = iokit.IOServiceGetMatchingServices(
    kIOMasterPortDefault,
    iokit.IOServiceMatching('IOSerialBSDClient'),
    ctypes.byref(serial_port_iterator)
)
print('serial_port_iterator =', serial_port_iterator)
```

If I run this under python2, then it works properly:

```
382 >python bug.py 
('kIOMasterPortDefault =', c_void_p(None))
('serial_port_iterator =', c_void_p(4355))
```

However, when I run it under Python3, it fails (serial_port_iterator stays as c_void_p(None))

```
383 >python3 bug.py
kIOMasterPortDefault = c_void_p(None)
serial_port_iterator = c_void_p(None)
```

Does anybody know why this would be failing under Python3, and perhaps how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

ok - figured it out.

Python3 passes strings as unicode (wide) strings, whereas Python2 passes strings as narrow strings.

So changing this line

```
iokit.IOServiceMatching('IOSerialBSDClient'),
```

to read

```
iokit.IOServiceMatching(b'IOSerialBSDClient'),
```

makes it work for Python2 and 3.

Now to see if I can get the change into pyserial.